# Displaying actual time

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to display the current time in my application. I want to get the current time from the server then just increment that so that I don't have to keep selecting the current time from the database every second. I also don't want to use something like `Date.Now().ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")` because of the possibility of client time being wrong.

So what i'm trying to do is get the server time in page load and just increment that. How would I do this?

Here's my code getting the time on page load from sql server

```
 con.Close()                                                                                                                     
 con.Open()                                                                                                                     
 Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("Select getdate() as date", con)
 Dim sqlreader As SqlDataReader = sqlcmd .ExecuteReader
 sqlreader.read                                                                                                                                                                            
 date1 = sqlreader("date")
 con.Close()

 Currenttime.Text = date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Now I just want to increment `Currenttime.Text` every second.

Comment: What kind of server do you want to retrieve the date from?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf Sql server, I know how to get the date from the server. What i'm trying to do is get that time once then increment that every second without selecting the time again.

Comment: What kind of accuracy are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx#Y0) Property in your server side application.

If you want to get it from your database, you can use [`GETDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188383.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the date from the sql server, compare it with the user's `Date.Now()` value to see what's is the difference between the sql server date.

```
Dim diff as TimeSpan = sqlDateTime - Date.Now()
```

Then, when you want to update the displayed date/time, apply the TimeSpan difference to the `Date.Now()` to adjust the local date with the server date.

```
Date.Now().addSeconds(diff.TotalSeconds).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
```

This code isn't perfect... first I didn't test it (I'm sure you'll understand the logic behind it), but you should also note that this won't work if the user change his system date/time after you calculated the TimeSpan.  If you need accuracy, you should also consider the fact that you'll loose some milliseconds while transferring the dateTime from sql server.

Depending on your needs, call the above code every x milliseconds using a Timer object to update the displayed date/time.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a timer from tool bar with 1000 millisecond interval and add a code to increment your time by 1 second.